# How to syntax highlight PHP in the Github Wiki

Tags: php, github, syntax-highlighting

So, I know how to do color coding in the github wiki. For example `json`:

`````
```json
  {}
````
`````

But for PHP this doesn't work

````
```php
// code here
```
````

I'll have to do this:

````
```
<?php
// code here
```
````

Or this:
    `php
    <?php
    // code here`

Which looks ugly, because you'll see the `<?php` in every block of code. Is there a way around this?

Comment: `\`\`\`php` should work, it always has for me. what do you actually see when you use it? And do you have a new line before the opening `\`\`\`php` and after the closing `\`\`\``?

Comment: yes! I have new lines. It only displays grey text, no color change anywhere

Comment: Any particular browsers? Or does it display the same in all browsers? If I view a typical code example in Chrome tools, there's a lot of spans with style classes for each syntax-highlighted block.... so perhaps you're missing the css definitions

Comment: @MarkBaker This is on GitHub, mot chrome tool or related > Github wiki

Comment: I'm viewing a github wiki page using a browser; didn't realise there was an alternative to using a browser.... sorry I can't be of any help then

Comment: of course it is a browser. But it doesn't render anything differently depending on browsers. But, it is the same on all browsers I've tested (chrome/firefox/safari)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've encountered this problem before as well. if you use: ```` ```php ```` it isn't enough. it requires a php open block `<?php` before it starts code highlighting. Its cross browser and is a pygments setting on the github servers. **Put a ticket in on github.**

> Pygments has a "startinline" option which is only relevant for the
>   PhpLexer. It allows syntax highlighting without the opening
>
> You can view the Pygments documentation on it here:
>   http://pygments.org/docs/lexers/ Search the page for startinline to
>   jump right to it.

### startinline

If given and True the lexer starts highlighting with php code (i.e.: no starting `<?php` required). The default is False.

Comment: So, I can't set this setting? Where do I put this ticket

Comment: no you cannot. I believe this would be the appropriate place to put it: https://github.com/github/markup

Comment: scratch that there is already a ticket here: https://github.com/github/markup/issues/107 its a year old and supposedly has been fixed, though we know that not to be the case. the issue was never closed. you should weigh in.

Comment: Alright, added comment there. It although seemed to be fixed for tickets/comments on tickets. But not yet in the wiki.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

As you can see [in this list](http://tinker.kotaweaver.com/blog/?p=152), that is compiled from [this pygments list](http://pygments.org/docs/lexers/), you should be able to use ```` ```php ```` without problems. If it doesnt work, try one of the following

- ```php
- ```php3
- ```php4
- ```php5
- ```css+php
- ```html+php
- ```js+php
- ```xml+php

Comment: this will not solve his issue each of these dec blocks has a Lexer in Pygments. the issue is that the php Lexer is not configured for his needs.